# Apache Nifi connection issue with kafka SASL_PLAINTEXT

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-nifi, jaas

I am using Kafka version 2.0.0. I have enabled SASL_PLAINTEXT In Kafka and tested from console producer and console consumer, and it's working for me.  Now I am trying to publish and consume the data from Nifi using consume Kafka and publish Kafka processors I could not able to do the connection. I am getting below error.

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: unable to find LoginModule class: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule

Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: unable to find LoginModule class: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule
```

Below is the configuration I did from the Nifi side.

I kept kafka_client_jaas.conf file in Nifi configuration path(/opt/nifi/nifi-1.9.2/conf/)

Below are the properties I used from Nifi

Security Protocol = SASL_PLAINTEXT

and  I am trying to add below properties but I am not getting the connection.

```
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
```

SASL mechanism is invalid because must be a known configuration mechanism for this Kafka client.

Answer (score 0):

I have used different publish and consume processor from Nifi Then it's worked for me

Comment: Im also facing same issue. could you please help me. can you please tell me what iprocessor version your using?